# Библиотека для работы с .doc файлами Apache POI, нужен пример работы

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, напишите пожалуйста  кoму не сложно код который удаляет первую строку в .doc файле при помощи библиотеки Apache POI . Желательно от начала и до конца объясните как работать с этой библиотекой. Разобрался бы сам времени катастрофически не хватает. Либо дайте пожалуйся код любой не большой программы с использованием Apache POI.

Comment: А что такое "первая строка" в .doc-файле? Первый абзац, наверное?

Comment: Да первый абзац.

Answer (score 1):

По идее это должно выглядеть как-то примерно так

```
HWPFDocument doc;
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile.doc")) {
    doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
}

doc.getRange().getParagraph(0).delete();

try (FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream("myfile-out.doc")) {
    doc.write(fos);
}
```

Но, по неизвестной причине это не работает: ворд (по крайней мере, мой Word Starter) говорит, что с документом что-то не так.. к тому же слетают стили..

Так что если нужно что-то надёжное, то похоже единственный надёжный вариант, это [OpenOffice в серверном режиме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625241/how-can-i-use-openoffice-in-server-mode-as-a-multithreaded-service). Но, изучение этого способа - задача совсем непростая.. нет, не простая..

Comment: Я добавил библиотеку в проект, какие надо поключить классы чтобы этот код хотябы распознался компилятором? 
import . . .

Comment: О, я подключал мавеном из группы org.apache.poi артефакты poi и poi-scratchpad

Comment: Да на этот код мой word тоже ругается. Может заного попробовать задать свойства документа средствами Apache POI? Или они должны были сохраниться?

Comment: По идее всё это должно поддерживаться.. и всё же там явно какие-то баги, так что редактировать документы им видимо всё ещё опасно.